# How To Get Values From Cells In Radgrid C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rows, radgrid, cells

I am trying to get specific cell value so i can pass it in my method when i press the button but i get always null on both (and i know that is not null).

P.s: None row is selected because i made a loop to get all the rows. The variable "p" is getting correct the number of the rows that i have on the grid.

```
  protected void PostRadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int p;
            if (DocStatTxtBox.Text == "2")
            {
                foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items)
                {
                    p = item.RowIndex;
                    string itemcodeparam = item["ItemCode"].Text;//error null (4th cell)
                    int quantityparam = Convert.ToInt16(item.Cells[5].Text);//error null
                    Boolean x = Methods.UpdateStock(WhTxtBoxRadDropDownList.SelectedValue,itemcodeparam,-quantityparam);


                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did it with this code

```
protected void PostRadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int p;
                if (DocStatTxtBox.Text == "2")
                {
                    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items)
                    {

                            p = item.RowIndex;

                            Label itemparam = (Label)item["ItemCode"].FindControl("ItemCodeLabel");
                            Label qparam = (Label)item["Quantity"].FindControl("QuantityLabel");


                            string itemcodeparam = itemparam.Text;
                            int quantityparam = Convert.ToInt16(qparam.Text);
                            Boolean x = Methods.UpdateStock(WhTxtBoxRadDropDownList.SelectedValue, itemcodeparam, -quantityparam);


                    }
                }
            }
```